# NSTimers causing leaks

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, nstimer

I've read up a lot about NSTimers, but I must be doing something very wrong with them, because it's practically all the leaks that show up in the Leaks Instrument. The "Responsible Frame" column says -[NSCFTimer or +[NSTimer(NSTimer).

So here's how I have an NSTimer set up in my main menu.  I shortened it up to just show how the timer is setup.

.h -

```
@interface MainMenu : UIView {
    NSTimer *timer_porthole;    
}

@end


@interface MainMenu ()

-(void) onTimer_porthole:(NSTimer*)timer;


@end
```

.m -

(in initWithFrame)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        timer_porthole = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(onTimer_porthole:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES] retain];

    }
    return self;
}
```

When leaving the view, it kills the timers:

```
-(void) kill_timers{
     [timer_porthole invalidate];
     timer_porthole=nil;
}
```

And of course, dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [timer_porthole invalidate];
    [timer_porthole release];
    timer_porthole = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call retain on your NSTimer!

I know it sounds counter-intuitive but when you create the instance it's automatically registered with the current (probaby main) threads run loop (NSRunLoop).  Here's what Apple have to say on the subject...

> Timers work in conjunction with run
> loops. To use a timer effectively, you
> should be aware of how run loops
> operate—see NSRunLoop and Threading
> Programming Guide. **Note in particular
> that run loops retain their timers, so
> you can release a timer after you have
> added it to a run loop.**
>
> Once scheduled on a run loop, the
> timer fires at the specified interval
> until it is invalidated. A
> non-repeating timer invalidates itself
> immediately after it fires. However,
> for a repeating timer, you must
> invalidate the timer object yourself
> by calling its invalidate method.
> Calling this method requests the
> removal of the timer from the current
> run loop; as a result, you should
> always call the invalidate method from
> the same thread on which the timer was
> installed. **Invalidating the timer
> immediately disables it so that it no
> longer affects the run loop. The run
> loop then removes and releases the
> timer, either just before the
> invalidate method returns or at some
> later point. Once invalidated, timer
> objects cannot be reused.**

- [Quotes are sourced from Apple's NSTimer class reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

So your instantiation becomes...

```
timer_porthole = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05
                                                           target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(onTimer_porthole:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
```

And now that you're no longer holding the reference to the instance you wont want the release call in your dealloc method.

Comment: Yes and no. Imagine situation where your timer has something to do with view controller A, is scheduled to fire in 10 seconds and user did move to another view controller in 5 seconds and you need to invalidate this timer, because it will fire after 5 seconds and you do not want it to fire for example.

Comment: It's a valid issue and as you pointed out in your own answer there are a few funky things going on with the OP's memory management.  But to me the most obvious source of the leak here is the superfluous retain.

Comment: For some reason I thought my app was crashing without the retain and I found that to be the issue... everything seems to be not leaking with that now. Thanks!

Comment: ... yeap - I made a reference to that in my response :)

Comment: Okay wait a minute, now it's crashing when I go to certain sections.  It does not show the leaks, which is great.. but the crashing.. why? Please help. 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData invalidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Wait.. I think it's because I'm calling release. I am not thinking obviously.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen you already accepted an answer but there are two things here that I wanted to rectify:

1. It's *not needed* to retain a scheduled timer but it doesn't do any harm (as long as you release it when it's no longer needed). The "problematic" part of a timer/target relationship is that...
2. **a timer retains its target**. And you've decided to set that target to `self`.
   That means — retained or not — the timer will keep your object alive, as long as the timer is valid.

With that in mind, let's revisit your code from bottom to top:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [timer_porthole invalidate]; // 1
    [timer_porthole release];
    timer_porthole = nil;  // 2

    [super dealloc];
}
```

**1** is pointless:
If `timer_porthole` was still a valid timer (i.e. scheduled on a runloop) it would retain your object, so this method wouldn't be called in the first place...

**2** no point here, either:
This is `dealloc`! When `[super dealloc]` returns, the memory that your instance occupied on the heap will be freed. Sure you can nil out your part of the heap before it gets freed. But why bother?

Then there is

```
-(void) kill_timers{
     [timer_porthole invalidate];
     timer_porthole=nil; // 3
}
```

**3** given your initializer (and as others have pointed out) you are leaking your timer here; there should be a `[timer_porthole release]` before this line.

---

PS:

If you think it all over, you'll see that retaining the timer (at least temporarily) creates a *retain-cycle*. In this particular case that happens to be a non-issue which is resolved as soon as the timer is invalidated...

Answer (score 0):

You missed `[timer_porthole release];` call in your `kill_timers` method. If you call `kill_timers` before `dealloc` method is called, you set `timer_porthole` to nil, but you did not release it.

Comment: Are you sure I should call the release in kill_timers?

Comment: If you call retain in initWithFrame, yes, you must call release too. If you do not retain it, you *must not* call release.

Comment: oh duh... this is what my problem is now. Thanks!

Comment: So I think in kill timers I just want invalidate, and thats it. No nil and obviously no release.