# Swift: NSTimer memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, memory-leaks, nstimer

i'm running a fast NSTimer (every 0.15s), and i see that approximately every 10 seconds the memory increase of about 0.5mb.

Here is my code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        //Prepare timer handshake
        if let tmr = self.tmrHandshake {
            tmr.invalidate()
            self.tmrHandshake = nil
        }
        self.tmrHandshake = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.sendLifeBeat), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.tmrHandshake!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    })
```

And the selector method:

```
dynamic private func sendLifeBeat() {
    let dataBytes = NSMutableData(data: lifebeatCmd.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    dataBytes.appendData(terminator.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    socketClient!.writeData(dataBytes, withTimeout: 5, tag: 1)
}
```

These "dispatch_async" is called inside a method that is running on a background thread.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTimers causing leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172711/nstimers-causing-leaks)

Comment: @CodeDifferent Hard to call `retain()` in Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

Make self a weak or unowned reference in the closure - you have a reference loop and it's not deallocating

Answer (score 0):

Profile your app using Instruments, choose the "Leaks" template, check "Discard events for freed memory" and "Enable NSZombie detection". Inspect the objects that don't get deallocated.

If you're using XCode 8, you should see memory leaks in the "Issue Navigator" under "Runtime".

This is what I'd do when I found a leak. Try to debug it yourself, I cannot see any bad code in your example.